# Python. Замена символов только в начале и конце строки

Tags: python, строки, список, списки, замена

Имеется список, состоящий из элементов-строк, которые, в свою очередь, состоят из букв и тире. Примерно так:

```
   ['---atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca------',
    'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca---',
    'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg']
```

Задача: сделать так, чтобы тире в начале и в конце элементов-строк заменились на точки, а тире, стоящие в середине строк, остались неизменными. При этом нужно в итоге получить также список. Вот так:

```
['...atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca......',
 'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca...',
 'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg']
```

Полагаю, что придётся преобразовывать каждый элемент в отдельный список. Но в целом не знаю, как решить эту задачу. Буду премного благодарен за решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если развлечься, и не использовать регулярки, то получится что-то такое:

```
def dash_dot(s):
    n = len(s)
    return  '.' * (n - len(s.lstrip('-'))) + s.strip('-') + '.' * (n - len(s.rstrip('-')))

x = ['---atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca------',
     'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca---',
     'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg']
print([dash_dot(s) for s in x])
```

P.S. Ой... строчку из одних минусов отработает неправильно, если оно встречается, надо отдельное условие поставить на `s.strip('-') == ''`

Answer (score 1):

Найти индексы в строке первой и последней буквы, и всё, что до первой буквы и после последней (по условию, кроме тире там ничего нет), замениить на точки можно с помощью такой функции:

```
def replace_on_borders(string):
    first_letter_idx = len(string)
    last_letter_idx = 0
    for idx, letter in enumerate(string):
        if letter.isalpha():
            if idx > last_letter_idx:
                last_letter_idx = idx
            if idx < first_letter_idx:
                first_letter_idx = idx
    return ''.join(['.' * (first_letter_idx),
                    string[first_letter_idx:last_letter_idx+1],
                    '.' * (len(string) - last_letter_idx - 1)])
```

Новый список можно создать при помощи генератора списков:

```
old_strings = [
    '---atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca------',
    'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca---',
    'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg'
]
new_strings = [replace_on_borders(string) for string in old_strings]
```

Вывод таких команд

```
import pprint
pprint=pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint
pprint(new_strings)
```

Получается следующий:

```
[   '...atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca......',
    'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca...',
    'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg']
```

то есть, вроде, всё, как и надо

Answer (score 1):

Задачу можно решить с использованием регулярных выражений, производя замену по шаблону.

Используем следующие шаблоны: `(^-*)` - дефисы в начале строки, `(-*$)` - в конце строки.

В функции замены получаем длину группы совпадения, возвращаем сооветствующую последовательность точек.

```
import re

ls = '---atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca------',\
     'tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca---',\
     'gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg'

def repl(match):
    return '.' * len(match.group())

patt = re.compile(r'(^-*)|(-*$)')

for i in ls:
    print(patt.sub(repl, i))

# ...atcggctacgt--tactgcatgtca......
# tc---------agtacgtactactgacgtca...
# gcgtatagcgttga--------cgtgacgtacgg
```

Формирование списка:

```
dotted_lst = [patt.sub(repl, i) for i in ls]
```